# How to Start Postgres Service in MacOs?

Tags: macos, homebrew, postgresql

I already install PostgreSQL using homebrew "brew install postgresql". But after that, I will start the service of the Postgres service its give me some error message.

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

> waiting for server to start....2019-04-28 11:59:51.107 IST [9563] LOG:
>   listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432 2019-04-28 11:59:51.107 IST
>   [9563] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
>   2019-04-28 11:59:51.109 IST [9563] LOG:  listening on Unix socket
>   "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" 2019-04-28 11:59:51.119 IST [9563] LOG:  could
>   not open directory "pg_tblspc": No such file or directory 2019-04-28
>   11:59:51.123 IST [9564] LOG:  database system was shut down at
>   2019-03-31 19:13:06 IST 2019-04-28 11:59:51.123 IST [9564] LOG:  could
>   not open directory "pg_tblspc": No such file or directory 2019-04-28
>   11:59:51.123 IST [9564] FATAL:  could not open directory
>   "pg_replslot": No such file or directory 2019-04-28 11:59:51.124 IST
>   [9563] LOG:  startup process (PID 9564) exited with exit code 1
>   2019-04-28 11:59:51.124 IST [9563] LOG:  aborting startup due to
>   startup process failure 2019-04-28 11:59:51.125 IST [9563] LOG: 
>   database system is shut down  stopped waiting pg_ctl: could not start
>   server Examine the log output.

And I also not find out the pg_hba.conf file to change's socket related issue.

Comment: I used to struggle with problems like this, then I discovered https://postgresapp.com  No, no connection, just a happy user.

Comment: Can you please replace the error message part by copying/pasting directly from Terminal and then applying code formatting to the whole block (the `{}` icon on top of the edit window)? Right now it's extremely hard to read.

Comment: Also, have you used Postgres before? By default a newly installed Progress just starts up empty, yours seems to know about a tablespace file already. You may also want to check the permissions of `/usr/local/var/postgres` and its content to make sure the current user (the one calling `pg_ctl` is allowed to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this should do the trick:

"pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start"
Without the " " of course.